# Screenfly alternative for testing Drupal 8 sites

Tags: 8, theming, testing

For Responsive screen testing I am using Screenfly (http://quirktools.com/screenfly/).

Drupal 8 can not be displayed inside an iframe (see [link](https://dev.acquia.com/blog/drupal-8/10-ways-drupal-8-will-be-more-secure/2015/08/27/6621), par. 9). This is the reason why Screenfly can not be used to test Drupal 8 sites by default.

Are there any alternatives to Screenfly for responsive screen testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html?brand=CHBD&gclid=Cj0KEQjwgJq-BRCFqcLW8_DU9agBEiQAz8Koh0x3zsk5LyE3vg244Eg_1SmBsUfhlLVTzVLvQwUfW14aAmWe8P8HAQ) <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> also known as *right click* >> *Inspect*

Once the Developer Tools is open, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> or click the 2nd icon

[image]

[image]

**With Responsive, you can resize to whatever you want by dragging the right border**

Comment: Interesting ... Too bad you can't select (yet?) something like a good old 3270 screen (aka mainframe) ... After all, there is z/Linux these days (to run Linux on a mainframe), so you might as well want to know how it looks like on a "handheld mainframe" ... hm hm ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens wow, I haven't heard the word "mainframe" in a long time, reminds me of a [childhood cartoon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108903/) I used to watch.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend setting up Seleniums Docker solution. I use that to run Behat tests in, you can define multiple profiles in the behat.yml file. Using Chrome driver, each profile an be a different device emulation mode in Chrome. Then when you run behat - just pass a runtime arg telling it which profile to use.

I also recommend checking out the Drupal Behat Extension.

You may also want to look into visual regression testing as well.